# Drawing usecase for Enter Phone number scenario - Beginner

Tags: uml, use-case, rational-rose

I need to draw a usecase that will expect the user to enter the phone number. But the user will be given 2 attempts to enter the phone number. If both 2 attempts fail, then he will be asked to sign in to the system. How can i draw the usecase for this system ?

[image]

What i want to show:

1.) I want to show that a user can only attempt 2 tries to `enter the phone number`, If both attempts were wrong he will be asked to `Login to the system`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not something to be modeled on use-case diagram. Such resolution is reserved to a lower-level modeling corresponding to your `Login to the system` use-case, such as sequence or activity diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely agree. Use a sequence diagram to model behavior. Use-cases should be used to show high-level interaction with the system. In your case, two use cases: `Login to the system` and `Enter Phone #`

Comment: Since the user does not access their functionality directly, I wouldn't model them as use-cases

Comment: The `Company System` is directly connected to `Validate Phone Number` (Validation is done in by another system). (Not shown in this diagram). If so is it correct ?